# Linux/CentOS: How to force FTP/SSH to use a particular ethernet adapter

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

We have a CentOS server with 2 ethernet adapters. Both of these adapters have access to the internet and both can be used to connect to remote sites.

Is there a way to know which ethernet adapter will be used when connecting to an FTP server or connecting via SSH to another server? If so, is there a way to force it to use a particular adapter without disabling any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can set up a special route for the servers you intend to connect to? Have a look at the route command, or the "ip route" command.

EDIT: This seems to contain an example of what I'm saying: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-configuring-default-route-with-ipcommand/

Specifically:

> Type the following command to sent all packets to the local  enter
>   code herenetwork 192.168.1.0 directly   through the device eth0:,
>   enter

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

For ssh, you can use the `BindAddress` ssh_config option. You can specify it on the command line with the `-o` option.

Comment: Yup, you can use clients that allow specifying which source address (or interface) to bind to, but you probably also need to fool around with ip route a bit and specify different routes based on source address... either default route for the whole internet, or just specific routes for some servers you want to connect to.